# multiple Rabbitmq queues with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, rabbitmq-exchange

From spring boot tutorial:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/

They give an example of creating 1 queue and 1 queue only, but, what if I want to be able to create more then 1 queue? how would it be possible?

Obviously, I can't just create the same bean twice:

```
@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(queueNameAAA, false);
}

@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(queueNameBBB, false);
}
```

You can't create the same bean twice, it will make ambiguous.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Give the bean definition factory methods different names. Usually, by convention, you would name them the same as the queue, but that's not required...

```
@Bean
Queue queue1() {
    return new Queue(queueNameAAA, false);
}

@Bean
Queue queue2() {
    return new Queue(queueNameBBB, false); 
}
```

The method name is the bean name.

**EDIT**

When using the queues in the binding beans, there are two options:

```
@Bean
Binding binding1(@Qualifier("queue1") Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(queueNameAAA);
}

@Bean
Binding binding2(@Qualifier("queue2") Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(queueNameBBB);
}
```

or

```
@Bean
Binding binding1(TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue1()).to(exchange).with(queueNameAAA);
}

@Bean
Binding binding2(TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue2()).to(exchange).with(queueNameBBB);
}
```

or even better...

```
@Bean
Binding binding1(TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue1()).to(exchange).with(queue1().getName());
}

@Bean
Binding binding2(TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue2()).to(exchange).with(queue2().getName());
}
```

Comment: but, once i have 2 beans, as you can see in the link to tutorial, the method name "binding" you only get 1 queue, so how would you bind this based on your own needs? I mean, I'm trying to bind multiple queue into 1 exchange, using different keys for the queues. but spring boot doesn't provide this.

Comment: Ah, I see you are just not yet familiar with Spring configuration - see my edit.

Comment: OMG, seems like a lot of things which are unrelated to this question, become crazingly clear....Thank you very much, u made me a super human :)