# how to create multiple(20-30) rabbitMQ queue using loop in spring boot

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

not helpful: [multiple Rabbitmq queues with spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210688/multiple-rabbitmq-queues-with-spring-boot/59770830#59770830)

Answer (score 1):

@Gary Russell Thanks it worked well. another example.

```
public DirectExchange exchange(RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin) {
    DirectExchange directExchange = new DirectExchange("exchangeName", true, false);
    rabbitAdmin.declareExchange(directExchange);
    for (int num = 1; num <= 20; num++) {
        Queue queue = new Queue("queueName" + num, true, false, false, null);
        rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
        rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(directExchange).with("routingKey" + num));
    }

    return directExchange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `RabbitAdmin.declareQueue()` in a loop.

```java
    List<Queue> queues = new ArrayList<>();

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitAdmin admin) {
        return args -> this.queues.forEach(queue -> admin.declareQueue(queue)); 
    }
```

Comment: This would be a much better answer with an example.

Comment: Seriously? Example addeed.

Comment: Yes, and thank you.  The pre-example version showed up in the Low Quality Posts queue.  Rather than voting to close, I wrote the comment.  This will help those with little experience.